# Haskell: How to solve possible version conflict?

Tags: haskell

I'm possibly having some trouble with dependency issues, but not entirely sure.  Here's my problem.  I'm using the Data.Bson library, and converting some (Text, Text) tuple into bson Fields, and when I define this function:

```
typeMismatch :: (Text, Text) -> Field
typeMismatch tp = (fst tp) := (String (snd tp))
```

it complains:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Label' with actual type `Text'
Expected type: (Label, b0)
  Actual type: (Text, Text)
```

`Field` is basically just a key/value in Bson, with the key being a `Label`, defined as a synonym for `Text`, and value being `Value`, with `String` being one of its many constructors (i.e. this is not the `Prelude.String`).  Now I try changing the 1st Text to Label:

```
typeMismatch :: (Label, Text) -> Field
typeMismatch tp = (fst tp) := (String (snd tp))
```

So the Label matches, though it's not what I want, I'm just doing this to investigate, but it still complains:

```
Couldn't match expected type `text-0.11.2.0:Data.Text.Internal.Text'
            with actual type `Text'
Expected type: (Label, text-0.11.2.0:Data.Text.Internal.Text)
  Actual type: (Label, Text)
```

And it looks like I have some dependency issues or module import issues.  But I checked my libraries and it seems like bson uses text-0.11.2.0 and data.text is also just text-0.11.2.0, so everything should be consistent.

How do I resolve this problem?  Thanks in advance.

EDIT: solved.  check dependencies when compiling by adding the "-v" flag.  for some reason there's also text-0.11.2.2 lurking there somewhere.  ghc-pkg unregister that package and it compiles.  i'll need to start learning how to avoid "haskell dependency hell" from now on.

Comment: Are you importing the correct `Text` type (i.e. Text and not Text.Lazy)?

Comment: I'm importing just Data.Text, and Data.Bson.

Comment: You can compile your program with `-v` flag and show which packages a loading and why.

Comment: Ah!  I see "hiding package text-0.11.2.0 to avoid conflict with later version text-0.11.2.2" along with a bunch of other "hiding packages xxx" messages.  I can't unregister text-0.11.2.0 without breaking a ton of stuff, but unregistering text-0.11.2.2 seems to do the trick--plus no dependencies on it!  I see what people mean by dependency hell now... Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use two versions of the same package?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819272/how-can-i-use-two-versions-of-the-same-package)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most of cases, you can avoid dependency hell with `cabal-dev` and specifying packages versions in your `.cabal` file.

Comment: yeah... i didn't install cabal-dev and i guess i need start doing it now!

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/Paczesiowa/hsenv is another option too. I find it to be a little more transparent than `cabal-dev`, and if you've used either rvm or virtualenv, you already know how to use make it work.